# Login To Magento version 1.5.0.1 from outside website

Tags: magento, authentication

I am trying to login to Magento Admin pannel from out side website but unable to find any way out.My Magento version is 1.5.0.1.  I tried the code on url : http://mysillypointofview.richardferaro.com/2010/03/25/how-to-run-magento-version-1-4-0-1-session-to-external-site/#comment-4103  but the code mentioned here is for version 1.4.0.1.

Comment: You haven't said what goes wrong or what information you're trying to display from the admin.

Answer (score 0):

may be you need build 2 client both customize app and magento side
1.create php file to verify magento username
2.send request to magento for authenticate

Answer (score 0):

Create file and try it

```
require_once "app/Mage.php";

umask(0); 

Mage::app();

//  require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/mage1/app/Mage.php";

// Customer Information

$firstname = "krishana";

$lastname = "singh";

$email = "krish.bhati@gmail.com";

$password = "myverysecretpassword";


// Website and Store details

$websiteId = Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId();

$store = Mage::app()->getStore();

$customer = Mage::getModel("customer/customer");

$customer->website_id = $websiteId;

$customer->setStore($store);


$mageRunCode = isset ( $_SERVER ['MAGE_RUN_CODE'] ) ? $_SERVER ['MAGE_RUN_CODE'] : '';

$mageRunType = isset ( $_SERVER ['MAGE_RUN_TYPE'] ) ? $_SERVER ['MAGE_RUN_TYPE'] : 'store';

$app = Mage::app ( $mageRunCode, $mageRunType );

Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'frontend')); 

$session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');

$session->start();

$customer->loadByEmail($email); 

$customer_id= $customer->getId();


if($customer_id){   

Mage_Core_Model_Session_Abstract_Varien::start();

$session->login($email, $password);

$session->setCustomerAsLoggedIn($session->getCustomer()); 

echo $session->isLoggedIn() ? $session->getCustomer()->getName().' is online!' : 'not logged in';


}
```